# mysql query not ending

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have 4 tables.

```
person ... PersonID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME 

users ...  PersonID, IsApproved

membership ... MembershipID,  LastActiveYear
```

Last table ties them all together

```
mempershipperson ... MembershipID,   PersonID
```

I need to generate list, showing;

`SELECT 'LASTNAME','FIRSTNAME','PersonID','MembershipID'

WHERE 'LastActiveYear' <= 2013
AND 'IsApproved" = 1`

When I run this query below it seams to go on for ever. I should have about 100 rows.

`SELECT LastActiveyear, M.MembershipID, P.FIRSTNAME, P.LASTNAME, U.IsApproved
FROM`membership`M,`users`U,`person`P
JOIN`membershipperson`MP ON MP.PersonID = P.PersonID
WHERE`LastActiveYear`= 2012 AND`IsApproved`= 1`

I'm am very new to all this so it may be very apparent just what I'm doing wrong to you.
I have been struggling with this for a couple of weeks. So of my attempts have returned over 700,000 rows of useless data.

At some point I need to create a php page to reset all these errant IsActive bits to '0'.

Note that the tables have many more columns, I am just showing the pertinent ones for this application.

Thank you

Comment: You don't specify a criteria for the join on Users or Membership; so the database is joining every row with every other row.

Comment: do a join on users and person rather than including it in your FROM section

Comment: @andrewsi, that should be the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT LastActiveyear, M.MembershipID, P.FIRSTNAME, P.LASTNAME, U.IsApproved
FROM `membership` M
    JOIN `membershipperson` MP ON MP.MembershipID = M.MembershipID
    JOIN `users` U ON U.PersonID = MP.PersonID
    JOIN `person` P ON P.PersonID = MP.PersonID
WHERE `LastActiveYear` = 2012 AND `IsApproved` = 1
```

You need to work backwards from `membership`, to `membershipperson`, to `users` and `person`. The `JOIN` statements in the modified query above is doing that.

Comment: Thanks Michael, Now I have two options to look at, yours and Jessica's. This will take some time for me to try so I can't indicate if the answers are working for me just yet.

Comment: @BobCooper - actually, they've both given you the same answer, just with the JOINs in a separate order

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LastActiveyear, M.MembershipID, P.FIRSTNAME, P.LASTNAME, U.IsApproved
FROM `membership` M, 
INNER JOIN `users` U ON u.MembershipID = M.MembershipID (or UserID?)
INNER JOIN `person` P.PersonID onM.PersonID
INNER JOIN `membershipperson` MP ON MP.PersonID = P.PersonID
WHERE `LastActiveYear` = 2012 AND `IsApproved` = 1
```

Just curious, Why do you have users and person as two different tables?

Comment: Many thanks for all the quick response. I didn't design the db tables. It has to do with types of membership. If it is a family then all family members get the same 'MembershipID' but each gets a unique 'PersonID'